# How to load selected row's data in datagridview in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I have 10 rows in my access database in which each row contains info about individual person in columns like personid,personname,phoneno,city,street,pincode.
Here when I load these contents in datagridview all the 10 rows are getting displayed.
 But my problem is i want to display only a particular person's details in datagridview when he enters his name or id when he logs in.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Post the snippet you have tried

Comment: i have tried like this DataGridViewCellCollection selRowData = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells.value;  But it only shows the 1st row irrespective of the person

Comment: You have to specify a where clause Where person ID= your_loggedIn_PersonID